# ASP.NET Web API (Self Host) + Ninject - Default Bindings

Tags: ninject-2, asp.net-web-api, ninject-extensions

I'm converting a project from WCF Web API to ASP.NET Web API - thanks MS :(

Self Hosting POC code:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8080";
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
        config.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

        var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("The server is running....");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I'm registering Ninject as the dependency resolver. To accomplish this, I am using the `CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter` to register it:

```cs
config.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
```

This seems to work as far as I can tell although it feels a little dirty using SetResolver(object).

The problem I have now is when I try to run it there are a lot of bindings that are no longer registered (i.e. `IHttpContollerFactory`, `ILogger`, etc.).

Do I have to go through one-by-one and re-register all of the "default" dependencies?  It seems odd that defaults are registered with the default dependency resolver but I can't see a quick way to re-register the defaults when a new dependency resolver is set.  For something like the `ILogger`, I can't even seem to gain access to the default `System.Web.Http.Common.Logging.DiagnosticLogger` to make the binding.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to re-register the default services.  If you return null the framework will default back to it's internal DI container.  Also, in the latest bits it will only ask once.

Comment: Perhaps then the issue is that the NinjectServiceLocator is throwing an exception when a mapping isn't found. I'll investigate further.

Comment: @Discofunk  Yeah it does. But the framework will swallow that exception for you.

Comment: I see.  When running in debug VS2010 breaks on the exception but then seems to be swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it is probably better just to create a IDependencyResolver for Ninject.  I'm sure there will be a "proper" one created by someone whom has greater knowledge of Ninject but for now I'm using:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolverAdapter : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel; 

    public NinjectDependencyResolverAdapter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    #region Implementation of IDependencyResolver

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/sethwebster/NinjectDependencyResolver for a full implementation.